# TypeScript conditional types with enums

Tags: typescript, enums, conditional-types

I have the following TypeScript enum:

```js
enum UIConfigurationType {
  DisplayTableFields = "display-table-field",
  FormFields = "form-field",
  MainAttributes = "main-attribute",
  SearchAttributes = "search-attribute",
}
```

and this conditional type:

```js
type UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T extends UIConfigurationType> =
  T extends UIConfigurationType.DisplayTableFields
    ? "display-table-fields"
    : T extends UIConfigurationType.FormFields
    ? "form-fields"
    : T extends UIConfigurationType.MainAttributes
    ? "main-attributes"
    : T extends UIConfigurationType.SearchAttributes
    ? "search-attributes"
    : never;
```

which, for example, should statically return the literal type `"search-attributes"` for the generic literal type `UIConfigurationType.SearchAttributes` (and it actually does it right).

I have then the following function, which dynamically implements the mapping defined by the previous conditional type:

```js
function getUIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T extends UIConfigurationType>(
  uiConfigurationType: T
): UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T> {
  switch (uiConfigurationType) {
    case UIConfigurationType.DisplayTableFields:
      return "display-table-fields";
    case UIConfigurationType.FormFields:
      return "form-fields";
    case UIConfigurationType.MainAttributes:
      return "main-attributes";
    case UIConfigurationType.SearchAttributes:
      return "search-attributes";
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown uiConfigurationType: ${uiConfigurationType}`);
  }
}
```

This function definition causes TypeScript to raise errors in each case branch:

[TypeScript errors on `getUIConfigurationEntitySuffix` function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhGTv.png)

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! For whatever reason, TypeScript did not infer that the returned types are the right ones expected by `UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T>`, so I have to explicitly cast them:

```js
function getUIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T extends UIConfigurationType>(
  uiConfigurationType: T
): UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T> {
  switch (uiConfigurationType) {
    case UIConfigurationType.DisplayTableFields:
      return "display-table-fields" as UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T>;
    case UIConfigurationType.FormFields:
      return "form-fields" as UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T>;
    case UIConfigurationType.MainAttributes:
      return "main-attributes" as UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T>;
    case UIConfigurationType.SearchAttributes:
      return "search-attributes" as UIConfigurationEntitySuffix<T>;
    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown uiConfigurationType: ${uiConfigurationType}`);
  }
}
```